# Constructor & getter in Class of NodeJs is not working

Tags: node.js

Hi I have a problem at builder level and getter, I'm creating a small application of messages that are stored on the database. I used NodeJs for that, I created a class that allows to connect to the database and manage it,

The database contains a "message" table containing the string "id" "content" "creatd_d"
Here is the class code that I call message.js:

```
let connection = require("../config/connection")
let moment = require("moment")


class Message{

  constructor (row) { 
     return this.row = row
  }


  get content(){
    return this.row.content
  }

  get created_d(){
    return moment(this.row.created_d)
  }

  static create(content, cb){
    connection.query('INSERT INTO message SET content = ?, created_d = ?', [content, new Date()] , (err, results) => {
      if (err) throw err
      cb()

    });
  }


  static all(cb){
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM message order by created_d DESC', (err, rows) =>{ 
        if(err) throw err 
        cb(rows.map((row) => new Message(row))) }) }
  }


module.exports = Message
```

the goal of getter is to declare the module "moment" that allows to change the format of date, but the getter no longer works
Does anyone know, can this come from what please? thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean by `the getter no longer works`? Do you mean it worked in the past? What does it do and how does it differ from your expectations? How are you calling it?

Comment: I mean that the getter is not working if i declare in the page view "index.ejs"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the return in `return this.row = row` in the constructor. You are breaking the constructor and not returning the instance of Message.

Comment: if i remove the return, it show an erro that "row" is not defined

Comment: Where exactly in your code does it say that 'row' is not defined ? When I meant remove `return`, I meant just put `this.row = row;`

Comment: I put this.row = row , but it show me this: ReferenceError: C:\Users\MED BOUZLOU\Desktop\nodeprojet\views\pages\index.ejs:43
    41|    <div class="ui message">

    42|     <%= message.content %>

 >> 43|     <div class="ui date"><%= message.created_at %></div>

    44|    </div>

    45|    <br>

    46|    


row is not defined
    at Message.get created_at [as created_at] (C:\Users\MED BOUZLOU\Desktop\nodeprojet\models\message.js:14:10)

Comment: add a `console.log(row)` in your constructor and see if row is defined

Comment: it  was exactly show the RowDataPacket that i declare in `all` function but Where is the problem?

Comment: It sounds weird I need to test this on my side. I'm at work atm, don't have much time to test it on my own. I will do that later, sorry for the delay.

Comment: You're welcome, you can mark the answer as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

For more information of my problem; this is the page "index.ejs":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ma premier app de NodeJs</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/Semantic/semantic.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ui main container">
        <div class="ui fixed inverted menu">
            <a href="/" class="header item">Home</a>

        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h1>Bienvenue sur ma premier page ne NodeJs</h1>
        <% if (locals.flash && locals.flash.error) { %>
        <div class="ui negative message">
            <%= flash.error %>
        </div>
        <% } %>

        <% if (locals.flash && locals.flash.success) { %>
        <div class="ui positive message">
            <%= flash.success   %>
        </div>
        <% } %>

        <form action="/" method="post" class="ui form">
            <div class="field">
                <label for="message">Message</label>
                <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="ui red labeled submit icon button">
                <i class="icon edit"></i> Send
            </button>
        </form>
        <br>
        <h3>Les Messages</h3>
        <% for (message of messages){ %>
        <div class="message-item">
            <div class="ui message">
                <%= message.content %>
                <div class="ui date"><%= message.created_d %></div>
            </div>
            <br>

        </div>
        <%}%>


    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is the page serveur.js

```
let express = require("express")
let bodyParser = require("body-parser")
let session = require('express-session'); // Charge le middleware de session

let app = express()

//Moteur de template
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')


//Middleware
app.use('/assets', express.static("public"))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(session({
    secret: "monsession",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: false }
}))
app.use(require('./middlewares/flash.js'))

// Les Routes
app.get('/', (req, res) =>{

    let Message = require("./models/message")
    Message.all(function(messages){
        res.render('pages/index', {messages: messages})
    })


})

app.post('/', (req, res)=>{
    // test de disponibilité de message et si il est vide !!
    if (req.body.message === undefined || req.body.message === '') {
        req.flash('error', "Vous n'avez pas poster votre message")
        res.redirect('/')
        // res.render("pages/index", {error: "Vous n'avez pas entré aucun message"})
    }else{
        let Message = require("./models/message")
        Message.create(req.body.message, function(){
            req.flash('success', "Merci !")
            res.redirect('/')
        })
    }
})



app.listen(8080)
```

thaks